# Microsoft InfoPath

Tags: 2007, infopath, list

How to add data from sharepoint list to InfoPath form??

Comment: We need more information to properly answer your question. Please edit  your post and add details such as what you are trying to achieve. It will be  closed for now, but don't worry - once you have improved the question  flag a moderator and it can be reopened. See our [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Through the power of Google [I found you this](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=add+sharepoint+list+to+infopath).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another Google link for [Microsoft Office InfoPath](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=microsoft+office+infopath&aq=0&oq=microsoft+office+infop) links.